# how does terraform pass value of variable when it is not being referenced in main.tf

Tags: terraform

I don't understand the logic of the following terraform code, and not sure, but I guess it might be me, but would appreciate some help with this.

So there's the following module https://github.com/gettek/terraform-azurerm-policy-as-code/blob/main/modules/definition/main.tf

```
resource azurerm_policy_definition def {
  name         = local.policy_name
  display_name = local.display_name
  description  = local.description
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  mode         = var.policy_mode

  management_group_id = var.management_group_id

  metadata    = jsonencode(local.metadata)
  parameters  = length(local.parameters) > 0 ? jsonencode(local.parameters) : null
  policy_rule = jsonencode(local.policy_rule)

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  timeouts {
    read = "10m"
  }
}
```

and https://github.com/gettek/terraform-azurerm-policy-as-code/blob/main/modules/definition/variables.tf

```
variable management_group_id {
  type        = string
  description = "The management group scope at which the policy will be defined. Defaults to current Subscription if omitted. Changing this forces a new resource to be created."
  default     = null
}

variable policy_name {
  type        = string
  description = "Name to be used for this policy, when using the module library this should correspond to the correct category folder under /policies/policy_category/policy_name. Changing this forces a new resource to be created."
  default     = ""

  validation {
    condition     = length(var.policy_name) <= 64
    error_message = "Definition names have a maximum 64 character limit, ensure this matches the filename within the local policies library."
  }
}

variable display_name {
  type        = string
  description = "Display Name to be used for this policy"
  default     = ""

  validation {
    condition     = length(var.display_name) <= 128
    error_message = "Definition display names have a maximum 128 character limit."
  }
}

variable policy_description {
  type        = string
  description = "Policy definition description"
  default     = ""

  validation {
    condition     = length(var.policy_description) <= 512
    error_message = "Definition descriptions have a maximum 512 character limit."
  }
}

variable policy_mode {
  type        = string
  description = "The policy mode that allows you to specify which resource types will be evaluated, defaults to All. Possible values are All and Indexed"
  default     = "All"

  validation {
    condition     = var.policy_mode == "All" || var.policy_mode == "Indexed" || var.policy_mode == "Microsoft.Kubernetes.Data"
    error_message = "Policy mode possible values are: All, Indexed or Microsoft.Kubernetes.Data (In Preview). Other modes are only allowed in built-in policy definitions, these include Microsoft.ContainerService.Data, Microsoft.CustomerLockbox.Data, Microsoft.DataCatalog.Data, Microsoft.KeyVault.Data, Microsoft.MachineLearningServices.Data, Microsoft.Network.Data and Microsoft.Synapse.Data"
  }
}

variable policy_category {
  type        = string
  description = "The category of the policy, when using the module library this should correspond to the correct category folder under /policies/var.policy_category"
  default     = null
}

variable policy_version {
  type        = string
  description = "The version for this policy, if different from the one stored in the definition metadata, defaults to 1.0.0"
  default     = null
}

variable policy_rule {
  type        = any
  description = "The policy rule for the policy definition. This is a JSON object representing the rule that contains an if and a then block. Omitting this assumes the rules are located in /policies/var.policy_category/var.policy_name.json"
  default     = null
}

variable policy_parameters {
  type        = any
  description = "Parameters for the policy definition. This field is a JSON object that allows you to parameterise your policy definition. Omitting this assumes the parameters are located in /policies/var.policy_category/var.policy_name.json"
  default     = null
}

variable policy_metadata {
  type        = any
  description = "The metadata for the policy definition. This is a JSON object representing additional metadata that should be stored with the policy definition. Omitting this will fallback to meta in the definition or merge var.policy_category and var.policy_version"
  default     = null
}

variable file_path {
  type        = any
  description = "The filepath to the custom policy. Omitting this assumes the policy is located in the module library"
  default     = null
}

locals {
  # import the custom policy object from a library or specified file path
  policy_object = jsondecode(coalesce(try(
    file(var.file_path),
    file("${path.cwd}/policies/${title(var.policy_category)}/${var.policy_name}.json"),
    file("${path.root}/policies/${title(var.policy_category)}/${var.policy_name}.json"),
    file("${path.root}/../policies/${title(var.policy_category)}/${var.policy_name}.json"),
    file("${path.module}/../../policies/${title(var.policy_category)}/${var.policy_name}.json")
  )))

  # fallbacks
  title = title(replace(local.policy_name, "/-|_|\\s/", " "))
  category = coalesce(var.policy_category, try((local.policy_object).properties.metadata.category, "General"))
  version = coalesce(var.policy_version, try((local.policy_object).properties.metadata.version, "1.0.0"))

  # use local library attributes if runtime inputs are omitted
  policy_name = coalesce(var.policy_name, try((local.policy_object).name, null))
  display_name = coalesce(var.display_name, try((local.policy_object).properties.displayName, local.title))
  description = coalesce(var.policy_description, try((local.policy_object).properties.description, local.title))
  metadata = coalesce(var.policy_metadata, try((local.policy_object).properties.metadata, merge({ category = local.category },{ version = local.version })))
  parameters = coalesce(var.policy_parameters, try((local.policy_object).properties.parameters, null))
  policy_rule = coalesce(var.policy_rule, try((local.policy_object).properties.policyRule, null))

  # manually generate the definition Id to prevent "Invalid for_each argument" on set_assignment plan/apply
  definition_id = var.management_group_id != null ? "${var.management_group_id}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/${local.policy_name}" : azurerm_policy_definition.def.id
}
```

and an example how to use the module https://github.com/gettek/terraform-azurerm-policy-as-code/blob/main/examples/definitions.tf

```
module "deny_resource_types" {
  source              = "..//modules/definition"
  policy_name         = "deny_resource_types"
  display_name        = "Deny Azure Resource types"
  policy_category     = "General"
  management_group_id = data.azurerm_management_group.org.id
```

}

From how I see it (might be wrrong) a variable can be used as a default value to the local in a Terraform script. So how is the value for the variable `policy_name` used when `main.tf` references `local.policy_name` instead of `var.policy_name`. The variable `policy_name` is also not having a default value.

What am I missing ?

Thank you !

EDIT:

Thank you, very clear explanation. I think I understand it better now. So basically, when I’m calling the definition module Terraform essentially load and process that module’s configuration files (including variables.tf). I was confused to see `name         = local.policy_name` instead of for example `mode         = var.policy_mode`. But the way I understand it now, is that when calling this module, I can set the value for the variable `policy_name`, which is then further processed inside the locals section, and result is what is actual provided to the `name` argument required by azurerm_policy_definition https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/policy_definition. Could you please confirm that my understanding is correct?

Thank you !

Comment: According to the declaration in the config you provided, it does have a default value.

Answer (score 1):

**policy_name** does have default value, but the value is empty.

```
default     = ""
```

Empty value can be default value. Terraform expects module inputs only when there is no default attribute set in the input field.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so there are two scenarios at play here.

1. When the `policy_name` isn't provided to the module, it takes on its default behaviour of empty string
2. When a value is provided to the `policy_name`, the `locals` section transforms that value and then uses it in the code as `local.policy_name` for the resources. [L103](https://github.com/gettek/terraform-azurerm-policy-as-code/blob/main/modules/definition/variables.tf#L103)

```
policy_name = coalesce(var.policy_name, try((local.policy_object).name, null))
```

If you look for the [coalesce](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/coalesce) function, its purpose is to return the first element that is not `null`/empty.

Although, I don't see the point of that logic since if both cases are `null` it is supposed to return `null`. Could've used a simple condition instead.

I hope this clarifies things more.

*Ps: an empty string (`""`), Terraform consider as a value.*

Comment: thank you ! I’m sorry but I’m unable to upvote this due to reputation. Could you please refer to the EDIT section I’ve added just to confirm that the way I see it is correct ? Thank you!

Comment: @user211245 that's correct. They just made the module more complicated than it needs to be.